# Apostrophe causing problems with insert

Tags: php

Hi I am using php to insert some data into a MS Access Database, which works fine in most cases, the only time it doesnt work, as far as I can see is where there is an ' in the field, in this case its an address i.e. St John's Road.

This is the query statement I am using:

```
$sql = "insert into tempaddress (`id`, `StreetAddress`, `Place`, `PostCode`) values ('".$item["Id"]."', '".$item["StreetAddress"]."', '".$item["Place"]."','$SearchTerm')";  CustomQuery($sql);
```

And this is the error I am getting http://prntscr.com/58jncv

I'm fairly sure it can only be the ' within the string text that is messing it up, how can i change?

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

Apostrophes breaks SQL strings. So you should add slashes before each apostrophe in your SQL strings manually or use `PHP`'s built in function `addslashes()`.

Example:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO myTable (value) VALUES ('Text that shouldn't break')";

$sql = addslashes($sql); // outputs "INSERT INTO myTable (value) VALUES ('Text that shouldn\\'t break')"
```

Source : [php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, in the end I went with str_replace("'", "", $string);

Answer (score -1):

You are using ' ' quote with the php variable $SearchTerm and use a backslash before column name.

Change your query statement to this:

```
$sql = "insert into tempaddress (\`id\`, \`StreetAddress\`, \`Place\`, \`PostCode`) values ('".$item["Id"]."', '".$item["StreetAddress"]."', '".$item["Place"]."',$SearchTerm)";  CustomQuery($sql);
```

Comment: Its not the search term that is breaking its the '".$item["StreetAddress"]."'

Comment: No need to escape columns!